# Why do I get the error from AWS AppSync? Did I implemented something wrong?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, vtl

Hej community, I have a strange error (in my eyes).

The error tells that I have to use a JSON object instead of a String for request the graphQL API:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "validateCoupon": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "validateCoupon"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "MappingTemplate",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "Expected JSON object for attribute value '$[key][PK]' but got 'STRING' instead."
    }
  ]
}
```

But in the graphQL schema I specified:

```
validateCoupon(coupon: String!): CouponValidationResponse
```

for the "business logic I have implemented an vtl request template:

```
## GetItem operation for coupon item
#set($couponResult = {
    "version": "2018-05-29",
    "operation": "GetItem",
    "key": {
      "PK" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson("COUPON"),
      "SK" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson("COUPON#$ctx.args.coupon")
    }
})
$util.toJson($couponResult)

## GetItem operation for user metadata item
#if( $couponResult.Item.couponType == "PERCENTAGE" )
set($userResult = {
  "version" : "2018-05-29",
  "operation" : "GetItem",
  "key" : {
    "PK" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson("USER#$context.identity.sub"),
    "SK" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson("METADATA#$context.identity.sub")
  }
})
$util.toJson($userResult)
#end
```

May someone sees the error I am missing here. I absolutly not understand why he want a JSON object.